# Can I use the python API to convert object intersection coordinates to UV coordinates?

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, uv, geometry

Let's say I have a cube with a texture on it, and in edit mode I place the mouse cursor over some part of the cube. Is it possible to get the location of where the cursor is pointing (intersection test with cursor ray) and convert these coordinates to UV coordinates? And to also go the other way, given UV coordinate, find the object space coordinates? Can this be done with the Python API?

[image: Get coordinates of the X in object and UV coordinates]

Comment: The `UV -> object space` is more tricky, because the UV may point to several object space locations, or nowhere.

Comment: @zerocukor287 That's fine, it can be filtered after based on some criteria.

Comment: The first thing I think of is actual texture painting, so I might look into reusing that.